# How to handle different data types when creating a dynamic mongodb query in Mule

Tags: java, mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio

I am looking to create a dynamic mongodb query in Mule and have modified the Java Transformer code from this post to work with MongoDB: [Mule-Creating dynamic where condition for sql query through DB connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173832/mule-creating-dynamic-where-condition-for-sql-query-through-db-connector)

My query is what is the best way to handle different data types coming in as query parameters for the WHERE clause e.g. a string will have '' and boolean will be without quotes.

I am thinking that I will need to add an if statement which determines whether to use quotes or not based on the field names.

I just wanted to know if there is a better way because it feels like I am hard coding the values which is something I try to avoid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would be passing a `Document` type to find() method anyway right and you might already be using `<mongo:query-attribute>`

you can specify bson types for each of your query attribute. An example is shown below.

```
<mongo:query-attribute key="_id">
#[new org.bson.types.ObjectId('4c55576a5a42d6606cfa8267')]
</mongo:query-attribute>
```

you can get a full list of bson types here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/